# Retrieve data from arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to enter students' Id and Marks into an array. Problem statement is that if user enters the Id of student then Mark of that student should be displayed. Below is my code so far. Could you please help me?

```
int [] mark = new int [5] ;
string [] studentsid = new string [5];
string userInput = "";
bool found = false;
int i = 0;       

string[] answer = new string[5];
for (i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student " + (i + 1) + " 's ID Number: ");
    studentsid[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter student" + (i + 1) + "'s mark: ");
    mark[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("Enter one of you student's id number");

userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (studentsid[i].ToUpper() == userInput.ToUpper())
{
    found = true;
    Console.WriteLine(mark[i]);                           
}

if (mark[i] >=85 && mark[i] <= 100 )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Distinction");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're having?

Comment: This is a good *start* to a question, but especially when you are learning to code, you need to identify the actual problem a bit better. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: You're lacking a loop around the part of your code where you want to find the correct id, there rest of the code looks ok(ish).

Comment: my problem is that the when the user enters the student's id, his /her mark does not show up. so for example the student id that I entered is found in the second element in the array of the students id. the mark should be found in the second element of the array mark.  now what should i do to display the mark of this student?

Comment: That's what I said, you don't loop over the students so you're not going to find them...

Comment: @Maria I think this is a good sample for what you're trying to achieve: [https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/STUDENTS-MARK-REPORT-8488c868](Students mark report)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a second loop around the block of code that checks if the student's ID matches.

Right now, you are only checking if one student (the last student in the array) matches the user's input.  You are also using a for-loop's control variable outside of the loop, which is generally considered bad practice.

Consider something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter one of you student's id number");

userInput = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; i < studentsid.length; i++)
{
  if (studentsid[i].ToUpper() == userInput.ToUpper())
  {
      found = true;
      Console.WriteLine(mark[i]);                           
  }
}
```

Also, your "answers" array serves no purpose.  You only create it to check its hard-coded length of 5.  Use the length of studentsid instead.

Finally, two arrays aren't really the ideal way to store this type of data.
A map, using the student ID as the key and the mark as the value, would be a much more efficient way to store and access this data.

Comment: Great answer as it includes the fix + some constructive feedback.